WSL2 Docker Container can't connect to Host over Gateway IP
On my Linux Host docker containers I'm using following network settings to be able to connect to the host via the gateway IP 172.29.6.254:
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.29.0.0/16
          ip_range: 172.29.6.0/24
          gateway: 172.29.6.254

I wanted to do the same on my windows host with docker desktop (wsl2). I can ping the gateway, but connections are refused.
I thought it might end up in the wsl2 instance, but I opened a port with nc inside wsl2 and also can't connect to that. I can connect to the windows host by host.docker.internal, but I want to have a fixed IP address and not resolve the hostname.
Network inspect looks exactly the same like on my linux host:
docker network inspect dummy_default
[
    {
        "Name": "dummy_default",
        "Id": "a6fc9cc43abd262be542cea1bd1fef9f271a091bf32248e319664af96525ca4b",
        "Created": "2024-09-23T07:02:16.96548837Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.29.0.0/16",
                    "IPRange": "172.29.6.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "172.29.6.254"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "c69c0a57820d01116f2db8c4bf4870bce2b1d63743f93c3a6dd9e524f16faccd": {
                "Name": "bash",
                "EndpointID": "3694c8e65009e1560043a4d92f8809bb3e693eb5fcd8001c4ae7e802214406ad",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1d:06:00",
                "IPv4Address": "172.29.6.0/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "dummy",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.29.1"
        }
    }
]

Does anyone have some insight why this is not working and how I can debug it?

There are several layers of network here – the Linux VM has a network, and then each Docker network is a separate network – and things get confused if you try to tell Docker that the Docker network has host IP addresses.  You should almost never try to manually configure IP addresses in Docker at all, and most Compose applications never need to mention networks: either.  But also see From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine? for mechanisms Docker provides on its own.
